# How to select frame element for URLs with arguments?

Tags: javascript, dom

Sorry for newbie's question.

I have the following DOM tree:

[image]

I'm trying to find element with selector:

```
function elemhideForSelector(selector) {
  let elements = document.querySelectorAll(selector);
  console.log(elements.length + " elements found for " + selector);
  if (elements.length > 0) {
    for (let element of elements) {
     if (element.src == 'http://www.50statesclassifieds.com/image.php?size_id=11')
       hideElement(element);
    }
  }
}

elemhideForSelector("[src$='image.php?size_id=11'], [srcset$='image.php?size_id=11']");
```

But nothing is found:

> 09-20 15:46:22.830 15820-15820/org.chromium.chrome I/chromium: [INFO:CONSOLE(8)] "0 elements found for [src$='image.php?size_id=11'], [srcset$='image.php?size_id=11']", source:  (8)

UPDATE: it works in Chrome DevTools (but not in JS):

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason was it was called in wrong frame.